# MongoDB Modeling with Array of Documents

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, data-modeling

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class Model_Medication
{
    public ObjectId _id;

    public string name { set; get; }
    public List<Medication_Label> labels { set; get; }
}

public class Medication_Label
{
    public string ndc { set; get; }
    public string strength { set; get; }
    public ObjectId pill { set; get; }
}
```

and I'm getting this error: `FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'List<Medication_Label>' from BsonType 'Document'.`

Any suggestions or links to help me proceed?

Comment: i dont think so this code will give the error mentioned in the question.  please provide the relevant code

Comment: I updated it with the actual code. any suggestions?

Comment: Did code ever work?  If so did Net version change?  Did classes change between serializing and deserializing?

Comment: Again the required code is missing, in which line you are getting the exception

Comment: Can you try adding `public ObjectId _id;` to `Medication_Label`?

Comment: Did you register the classmap?

Comment: What does the data look like in your mongodb collection? `db.collection.find()`

Comment: probably it is because the data in the document is of type object